# Determining if an RTSP server is running and needs authentication

Tags: tcp, video-streaming, rtsp

I know that port 554 (typically RTSP) is open at a certain IP address. I'd like to be able to determine:

- Is this really an RTSP server?
- Is it possible to access the video stream without authenticating?

I'd also like to do this in as lightweight a fashion as possible. I don't need to access the video stream.

After looking through the RTSP spec I realized that I could simply open a TCP socket and send the following commands:

```
OPTIONS * RTSP/1.0<CRLF>
CSeq: 1<CRLF>
```

When I tried this against many servers I found that a handful responded with

```
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 1
<a bunch of other stuff>
```

This is to be expected. However, most requests that I made timed out. This leads me to believe that these resources require authentication or I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.

I'm guessing that most servers will respond with a 401 if authentication is required, so I'm probably doing something wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to RFC2326 of the RTSP protocol: [RFC2326](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2326#page-86)

> D.1.2 Authentication-enabled
>
> In order to access media presentations from RTSP servers that
> require    authentication, the client MUST additionally be able to do
> the    following:
>
> ```
>  * recognize the 401 status code;
>  * parse and include the WWW-Authenticate header;
>  * implement Basic Authentication and Digest Authentication.
> ```

Comment: If I receive a 401 that would be great. I'd know that I am talking to an RTSP server, it's up and running, and it requires authentication. My problem is that this is almost never the case. What I'm finding is that I'm receiving nothing and my requests are timing out leading me to believe that I'm doing something wrong. Is there anything in my approach which is incorrect?

Comment: You can try (http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/). This library has openRTSPTM client application. Try to connect to your server with "-v" option and trace all RTSP messages. Or you can also try with vlc for example.

Comment: So it turns out that my code was incorrect. I said that I was terminating all of my commands with <CRLF>, but my code was only sending "\n". When I began to use "\r\n" things began to work much better.

Comment: @SanderSmith is * really supported for URL path ? 
For me, hikvision says, its bad request